# Posting API from Javascript with fetch method

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have tried in posting API data Its working fine getting proper response ,but i try to do in JavaScript with fetch method through not getting , getting error Status Code: 500  message Invalid client credentials provided.Please check your required  your text header parameters.i was sent proper data as sending in postman

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam itaque numquam temporibus neque nemo consectetur debitis! Nisi, enim deleniti. Nostrum, beatae. Consequuntur, cum eaque harum at sunt deserunt recusandae eos.</h1>

    <script>
        const response =  fetch('https://einvoice.pos.bharuwa.com:6015/api/generateeinvoice', {
               method: "POST", 
               mode: "cors",
               header:
                      {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Content-Length":344,
                        "x-api-key": "C4789E11-555B-4CC7-9A69-BC1F35B8659E",
                        "x-clientId": "C4789E11-555B-4CC7-9A69-BC1F35B8659E",
                        "x-api-secret": "44461e58-7ab3-4cf7-b06e-9b68893e4902"
                      },
                      
    
  
                      body: {
                          "Version": "1.1",
                          "TranDtls": {
                            "TaxSch": "GST",
                            "SupTyp": "B2B",
                            "RegRev": "Y",
                            "EcmGstin": null,
                            "IgstOnIntra": "N"
                          },
                          "DocDtls": {
                            "Typ": "INV",
                            "No": "DOC/029",
                            "Dt": "09/08/2021"
                          },
                          "SellerDtls": {
                            "Gstin": "01AMBPG7773M002",
                                "LglNm": "ABC Travels Pvt Ltd",
                                "TrdNm": null,
                                "Addr1": "5th block, kuvempu layout",
                                "Addr2": null,
                                "Loc": "Jammu and Kashmir",
                                "Pin": 181102, 
                            "Stcd": "01",
                            "Ph": "9000000000",
                            "Em": "abc@gmail.com"
                          },
                          "BuyerDtls": {
                            "Gstin": "29AWGPV7107B1Z1",
                            "LglNm": "XYZ company pvt ltd",
                            "TrdNm": "XYZ Industries",
                            "Pos": "12",
                            "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
                            "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
                            "Loc": "GANDHINAGAR",
                            "Pin": 562160,
                            "Stcd": "29",
                            "Ph": "91111111111",
                            "Em": "xyz@yahoo.com"
                          },
                          "DispDtls": {
                            "Nm": "ABC company pvt ltd",
                            "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
                            "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
                            "Loc": "Banagalore",
                            "Pin": 562160,
                            "Stcd": "29"
                          },
                          "ShipDtls": {
                            "Gstin": "29AWGPV7107B1Z1",
                            "LglNm": "CBE company pvt ltd",
                            "TrdNm": "kuvempu layout",
                            "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
                            "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
                            "Loc": "Banagalore",
                            "Pin": 562160,
                            "Stcd": "29"
                          },
                          "ItemList": [
                            {
                              "SlNo": "1",
                              "PrdDesc": "Rice",
                              "IsServc": "N",
                              "HsnCd": "1001",
                              "Barcde": "123456",
                              "Qty": 100.345,
                              "FreeQty": 10,
                              "Unit": "BAG",
                              "UnitPrice": 99.545,
                              "TotAmt": 9988.84,
                              "Discount": 10,
                              "PreTaxVal": 1,
                              "AssAmt": 9978.84,
                              "GstRt": 12.0,
                              "IgstAmt": 1197.46,
                              "CgstAmt": 0,
                              "SgstAmt": 0,
                              "CesRt": 5,
                              "CesAmt": 498.94,
                              "CesNonAdvlAmt": 10,
                              "StateCesRt": 12,
                              "StateCesAmt": 1197.46,
                              "StateCesNonAdvlAmt": 5,
                              "OthChrg": 10,
                              "TotItemVal": 12897.7,
                              "OrdLineRef": "3256",
                              "OrgCntry": "AG",
                              "PrdSlNo": "12345",
                              "BchDtls": {
                                "Nm": "123456",
                                "ExpDt": "01/08/2021",
                                "WrDt": "01/09/2021"
                              },
                              "AttribDtls": [
                                {
                                  "Nm": "Rice",
                                  "Val": "10000"
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ],
                          "ValDtls": {
                            "AssVal": 9978.84,
                            "CgstVal": 0,
                            "SgstVal": 0,
                            "IgstVal": 1197.46,
                            "CesVal": 508.94,
                            "StCesVal": 1202.46,
                            "Discount": 10,
                            "OthChrg": 20,
                            "RndOffAmt": 0.3,
                            "TotInvVal": 12908,
                            "TotInvValFc": 12897.7
                          },
                          "PayDtls": {
                            "Nm": "ABCDE",
                            "AccDet": "5697389713210",
                            "Mode": "Cash",
                            "FinInsBr": "SBIN11000",
                            "PayTerm": "100",
                            "PayInstr": "Gift",
                            "CrTrn": "test",
                            "DirDr": "test",
                            "CrDay": 100,
                            "PaidAmt": 10000,
                            "PaymtDue": 5000
                          },
                          "RefDtls": {
                            "InvRm": "TEST",
                            "DocPerdDtls": {
                              "InvStDt": "01/08/2021",
                              "InvEndDt": "01/09/2021"
                            },
                            "PrecDocDtls": [
                              {
                                "InvNo": "DOC/004",
                                "InvDt": "01/08/2021",
                                "OthRefNo": "123456"
                              }
                            ],
                            "ContrDtls": [
                              {
                                "RecAdvRefr": "Doc/005",
                                "RecAdvDt": "01/08/2021",
                                "TendRefr": "Abc001",
                                "ContrRefr": "Co123",
                                "ExtRefr": "Yo456",
                                "ProjRefr": "Doc-457",
                                "PORefr": "Doc-790",
                                "PORefDt": "01/08/2021"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "AddlDocDtls": [
                            {
                              "Url": "https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in",
                              "Docs": "Test Doc",
                              "Info": "Document Test"
                            }
                          ],
                          "ExpDtls": {
                            "ShipBNo": "A-248",
                            "ShipBDt": "01/08/2021",
                            "Port": "INABG1",
                            "RefClm": "N",
                            "ForCur": "AED",
                            "CntCode": "AE",
                            "ExpDuty": null
                          },
                          "EwbDtls": {
                            "TransId": "12AWGPV7107B1Z1",
                            "TransName": "XYZ EXPORTS",
                            "Distance": 100,
                            "TransDocNo": "DOC03",
                            "VehNo": "ka123456",
                            "VehType": "R",
                            "TransMode": "1"
                          }
                        }, // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
                     });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Just checking - are you sure you want your API ids and secrets on here?

Comment: You need to turn your body object into a string first with `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1):

Before anything if that's real API creds I recommend removing it from post.

A few things I noticed and referencing [Fetch api doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for more details.

- your `header: {` property should be plural, `headers: {`
- wrap your JSON data with `JSON.stringify({...})` in the `body: JSON.stringify(yourJSONData)`
- recommend using async/await, see [Fetch api doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for an example

Working Example, just insert your creds.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam itaque numquam temporibus neque nemo consectetur debitis! Nisi, enim deleniti. Nostrum, beatae. Consequuntur, cum eaque harum at sunt deserunt recusandae eos.</h1>

    <script>
     async function postData() {
        const response = await fetch('https://einvoice.pos.bharuwa.com:6015/api/generateeinvoice', {
               method: "POST", 
               mode: "cors",
               headers:
                      {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Content-Length":344,
                        "x-api-key": "put-your-key",
                        "x-clientId": "put-your-key",
                        "x-api-secret": "put-your-key"
                      },
              body: JSON.stringify(
{
  "Version": "1.1",
  "TranDtls": {
    "TaxSch": "GST",
    "SupTyp": "B2B",
    "RegRev": "Y",
    "EcmGstin": null,
    "IgstOnIntra": "N"
  },
  "DocDtls": {
    "Typ": "INV",
    "No": "DOC/029",
    "Dt": "09/08/2021"
  },
  "SellerDtls": {
    "Gstin": "01AMBPG7773M002",
    "LglNm": "ABC Travels Pvt Ltd",
    "TrdNm": null,
    "Addr1": "5th block, kuvempu layout",
    "Addr2": null,
    "Loc": "Jammu and Kashmir",
    "Pin": 181102,
    "Stcd": "01",
    "Ph": "9000000000",
    "Em": "abc@gmail.com"
  },
  "BuyerDtls": {
    "Gstin": "29AWGPV7107B1Z1",
    "LglNm": "XYZ company pvt ltd",
    "TrdNm": "XYZ Industries",
    "Pos": "12",
    "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
    "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
    "Loc": "GANDHINAGAR",
    "Pin": 562160,
    "Stcd": "29",
    "Ph": "91111111111",
    "Em": "xyz@yahoo.com"
  },
  "DispDtls": {
    "Nm": "ABC company pvt ltd",
    "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
    "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
    "Loc": "Banagalore",
    "Pin": 562160,
    "Stcd": "29"
  },
  "ShipDtls": {
    "Gstin": "29AWGPV7107B1Z1",
    "LglNm": "CBE company pvt ltd",
    "TrdNm": "kuvempu layout",
    "Addr1": "7th block, kuvempu layout",
    "Addr2": "kuvempu layout",
    "Loc": "Banagalore",
    "Pin": 562160,
    "Stcd": "29"
  },
  "ItemList": [
    {
      "SlNo": "1",
      "PrdDesc": "Rice",
      "IsServc": "N",
      "HsnCd": "1001",
      "Barcde": "123456",
      "Qty": 100.345,
      "FreeQty": 10,
      "Unit": "BAG",
      "UnitPrice": 99.545,
      "TotAmt": 9988.84,
      "Discount": 10,
      "PreTaxVal": 1,
      "AssAmt": 9978.84,
      "GstRt": 12,
      "IgstAmt": 1197.46,
      "CgstAmt": 0,
      "SgstAmt": 0,
      "CesRt": 5,
      "CesAmt": 498.94,
      "CesNonAdvlAmt": 10,
      "StateCesRt": 12,
      "StateCesAmt": 1197.46,
      "StateCesNonAdvlAmt": 5,
      "OthChrg": 10,
      "TotItemVal": 12897.7,
      "OrdLineRef": "3256",
      "OrgCntry": "AG",
      "PrdSlNo": "12345",
      "BchDtls": {
        "Nm": "123456",
        "ExpDt": "01/08/2021",
        "WrDt": "01/09/2021"
      },
      "AttribDtls": [
        {
          "Nm": "Rice",
          "Val": "10000"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ValDtls": {
    "AssVal": 9978.84,
    "CgstVal": 0,
    "SgstVal": 0,
    "IgstVal": 1197.46,
    "CesVal": 508.94,
    "StCesVal": 1202.46,
    "Discount": 10,
    "OthChrg": 20,
    "RndOffAmt": 0.3,
    "TotInvVal": 12908,
    "TotInvValFc": 12897.7
  },
  "PayDtls": {
    "Nm": "ABCDE",
    "AccDet": "5697389713210",
    "Mode": "Cash",
    "FinInsBr": "SBIN11000",
    "PayTerm": "100",
    "PayInstr": "Gift",
    "CrTrn": "test",
    "DirDr": "test",
    "CrDay": 100,
    "PaidAmt": 10000,
    "PaymtDue": 5000
  },
  "RefDtls": {
    "InvRm": "TEST",
    "DocPerdDtls": {
      "InvStDt": "01/08/2021",
      "InvEndDt": "01/09/2021"
    },
    "PrecDocDtls": [
      {
        "InvNo": "DOC/004",
        "InvDt": "01/08/2021",
        "OthRefNo": "123456"
      }
    ],
    "ContrDtls": [
      {
        "RecAdvRefr": "Doc/005",
        "RecAdvDt": "01/08/2021",
        "TendRefr": "Abc001",
        "ContrRefr": "Co123",
        "ExtRefr": "Yo456",
        "ProjRefr": "Doc-457",
        "PORefr": "Doc-790",
        "PORefDt": "01/08/2021"
      }
    ]
  },
  "AddlDocDtls": [
    {
      "Url": "https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in",
      "Docs": "Test Doc",
      "Info": "Document Test"
    }
  ],
  "ExpDtls": {
    "ShipBNo": "A-248",
    "ShipBDt": "01/08/2021",
    "Port": "INABG1",
    "RefClm": "N",
    "ForCur": "AED",
    "CntCode": "AE",
    "ExpDuty": null
  },
  "EwbDtls": {
    "TransId": "12AWGPV7107B1Z1",
    "TransName": "XYZ EXPORTS",
    "Distance": 100,
    "TransDocNo": "DOC03",
    "VehNo": "ka123456",
    "VehType": "R",
    "TransMode": "1"
  }
}
              ) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        });
        return response.json();
     }
      
      
  postData().then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Status Code: 500 message Invalid client credentials provided" indicates that there is an issue with the credentials provided in the request headers.

In your JavaScript code, there seems to be a mistake in the header key name. It should be headers instead. Additionally, the Content-Length header should not be manually set, as it is calculated automatically. You can remove that header.